# the letter that he told you to deliver

Tags: infinitives, relative-clauses, ellipsis, postmodification

a. You didn't deliver the letter he told you.

b. You didn't deliver the letter he told you to.

a1. You didn't deliver the letter which he told you.

b1. You didn't deliver the letter which he told you to.

Are all of the above sentences grammatically correct?

Do they all have the same meaning?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, *none* of those sentences are grammatically correct.

When using a relative clause with "which" to modify a noun (and "a" and "b" are actually forms of this too, just with the "which" left out), an easy way to tell whether they are done correctly is that you should be able to change:

> A which B

into

> B A

(that is, move the first part to be after the second part and get rid of "which") and have it still make sense, In all of your examples, the clause at the end (following "which") is modifying the noun "the letter", so let's try your examples:

> the letter which he told you

becomes:

> he told you the letter

But "told" doesn't take a direct object like this.  That doesn't make sense for that verb (and even if it did, it's not what you meant to say).

Ok, howabout:

> the letter which he told you to

becomes:

> he told you to the letter

Well, that makes even less sense.

The root of the problem here is actually that the full action that relates to this letter is not actually "told" the letter, but "told to deliver" the letter.  "to deliver" is actually the infinitive form of "deliver" which is attached to "tell" to form a compound verb in this case.  But since the "to" in there is part of the infinitive, it can't be separated from its verb, so what you really have in the "to" forms of the examples are broken infinitives (and without the "to" it's just the wrong (non-compound) verb entirely).

So the only technically grammatically correct way to say this is:

> You didn't deliver the letter which he **told you to deliver**.

or

> You didn't deliver the letter he **told you to deliver**.

(leaving out the "which" is ok, but not leaving out "deliver")

As you can see, if we apply the trick above to this, we end up with:

> he told you to deliver the letter

Which is grammatically correct and is actually what we were intending to say (yay!)

Now, that having been said, when a verb is repeated like this, particularly at the end of a sentence or clause, even though it's technically wrong, it is very common for people to break the infinitive and leave off the second occurrence of the repeated word ("deliver"), so while it's not grammatically *correct*, sentences like your (b) and (b1) are often *accepted*:

> You didn't deliver the letter he told you to. *(wrong but often ok)*
>   You didn't deliver the letter which he told you to. *(wrong but often ok)*

Be aware, however, that since this is technically ungrammatical, it's generally only appropriate in casual speech, and should not be done when writing professionally or formally.

Your sentences (a) and (a1) just don't work at all, though, even casually.